# facebook javascript SDK - how can I insert the userdata to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, facebook, api

I want to use javascript sdk  because facebook php sdk new version doesnot support my company's PHP version.
Ok so... I want to insert the email of FacebookUser to database MySQL.
Please look at the fucntion get_Info(). I want the value of "response.email" parse to PHP variable and insert into MySQL,  but I don't know how to do because this variable is in the js function.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

  FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',  //Your appId
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
      document.getElementById('fb_login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook';
    }
  });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fb_login() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
      document.getElementById('fb_login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook';
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'email'
  });
}

function getInfo() {
  FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
    fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email'
  }, function(response) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.email;
  });

  FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
    fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email'
  }, function(response) {
    document.getElementById('status2').innerHTML = response.name;
  });
}

function fb_logout() {
  FB.logout(function() {
    document.location.reload();
  });
}
```

html

```
<div id="status"></div>   <div id="status2"></div>
                <button onclick="getInfo()"> Get Info</button>
                <button onclick="fb_login()" id="fb_login"> Login with Facebook </button>
                <button onclick="fb_logout()"> Log out </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use AJAX for that. If you want to pass JS data to PHP, make AJAX call. For example, you could do this:

### 1. Modify your `getInfo()` function like this:

```
function getInfo() {
  FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
    fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email'
  }, function(response) {
    var email = response.email;

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "path/to/your/file.php";
    var data = "email=" + email;
    http.open("POST", url, true);    
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    } 
    http.send(data);
  });
}
```

### 2. Create a `file.php` and write following code:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
    //Do whatever you want with your email
}
?>
```

What the code does is sending JS data to PHP file using simple AJAX call. In your `file.php` file you can do whatever you want with your data. In your case it'll be saving an email to database. I hope it will help

Comment: And what happens when you run this code? Did you check what happens with your request in the console (F12 -> Network)?

Comment: nothing error in console of browser  but your code alert : Undefined index: email in  mypath of otherpage.php  on the line 3.   my other page.php is look like your "file.php"  just have 7 line of code

Comment: Try modifying your request method to `GET`. In `getInfo()` function change the line to `http.open("GET", url, true);` and in your **otherpage.php** file change the code to `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    echo $email;
    //Do whatever you want with your email
}`

Comment: not working again  with same error but now, in other page.php,there is error message Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\new 1.php on line 3.    (while before see this on alert only)

Comment: Does your data even send properly? Go to the page which the button is at and hit [F12] to open a console and go to the Network tab. Then click the button and see if your request's status is OK

Comment: hmm in the page which button is at and hit   the network look like this. see the screenshot https://s17.postimg.org/j3rw104jx/image.jpg   and in the otherpage.php there is nothing in network.

Comment: i guess I should give my appId  for easily debug.     appId : '201637766943985'    please insert this in my code  and copy all of code and run to your web for test        these code not require plugin :)